# Qt Pairing Blutooth Device Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I am building an application in which I would like to pair a bluetooth low energy device and connect to it.
What should be the typical workflow for this

1. if the device bluetooth address is known
2. if the device bluetooth address is not known

Is QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent the class to do all this? If so, do you need to pair in the OS level (for instance using bluetooth icon in task bar) first or can it be done programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ble devices cannot be paired via settings in OS, because they can discover only bt classic devices. In ble devices bonding is not necessary, but sometimes is done for security reasons.

QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent class is only for discovering devices. For connecting to device is used [QLowEnergyController](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlowenergycontroller.html#connectToDevice) class. For more info I would refer to [Qt quides](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtbluetooth-le-overview.html) as I have only experience with Qt only with bluetooth classic devices